# CSS image with positiion absolute keep in div

Tags: css

I have `img` inside `div`. The image contains `position: absolute`.

```
<div id="page">
        <div class="content">
            <div class="post_container">
                <div class="post_content">
                    Mau beli e-book di Google Play? Pakai pulsa Telkomsel aja! Berkesempatan dapat hadiah di Festival #JajanOnline
                    Cek http://tsel.me/festival 

                    <div class="img">
                        <img src="https://scontent-sin6-1.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/sh0.08/e35/p640x640/17494073_1872822862961864_3051963374960115712_n.jpg"/>
                    </div>

                    <div class="post_action">
                        Comment
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
#page .content
{
position: absolute;
margin-top: 10px;
width: 1000px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
left: 0;
right: 0;
}

#page .content .post_container
{
width: 500px;
border: 1px solid #dddddd;
}

#page .content .post_container .post_content
{
background: #fff;
}

#page .content .post_container .post_content .img
{
position: relative;
}

#page .content .post_container .post_content .img img
{
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
clip: rect(0, 500px, 400px, 0);
}
```

I want the `img` keep inside div. The fact: the image is not inside.

You can see in the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0uv1hy38/1/) for the demo.

I don't want to use height/min-height on post_container.

Comment: `The image contains position: absolute;` why dont you remove it then? it works that way

Comment: Can't remove it, because I set it to display just a portion of an image. If I remove it the image will display full

Answer (score 0):

First, try to avoid calling a class img. Reserve that for the element, as this can get confusing while looking at your code. try calling it img-container. Set that container to width: 90% and center it with margin: auto. Then add some margin to the container to give it some space from the text.

Working with what you have already set up try this:

```
#page .content .post_container .post_content .img
{
  position: relative;
  width: 90%;
  margin: 10px auto;
}

#page .content .post_container .post_content .img img
{
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    clip: rect(0, 500px, 400px, 0);
}
```